# What kind of visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, south-africa

My partner is a retired British citizen (Scottish) He owns a home in Glasgow. He is presently living in Cape Town. I have a South African passport and am a SA resident. We are hoping to share our time (as a retired couple) between the UK and SA. What sort of visa will allow for this?

Comment: Questions about living in a place long-term are off-topic, here and should be asked at [expatriates.se], instead. Also, you should probably split this up into two questions: what you'll need for your time in the UK and what he'll need for his time in SA. Plenty of people will know the answer to one half of the question but probalby not many will know both. And people in the future who only want to know about, e.g., the UK half will find it hard to get the information they need because of the SA answers.

Comment: @Kathy Smit You say your partner is a British citizen living in Cape Town - what is his residence status in SA?